# How do I avoid creating 65 separate SharePoint workflows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I would like to send an email notification to a specific user based on the Category field in my SharePoint list. I currently have 65 choices for Category. i.e. new item posted in the 3D category, an automated message should go to John Doe.

How can I do this so that I don't have to create 65 workflows - or 65 steps in one workflow!? Any thoughts appreciated. The user submitting the new item will not know who to 'assign' the item to.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in the past:

1. Add another column to the Category list that contains the user that should receive the email when that category is selected.
2. When the workflow runs, lookup the user in the Category list based on the Category selected and set it to a workflow variable
3. Log the workflow variable (for troubleshooting) and set the "To" field to the variable.

Comment: this will also solve the 65 different e-mail addresses you need to use SPD to modify issue too :)